Is there an electric field due to current carrying wire?
In a current carrying conductor with non variable current there is a magnetic field outside but is there an electric field? We take out the magnetic field by biot savart law but how does the electric field work? Does it exert force of the object in motion outside the wire?

If the current flows in a conductor with non-zero resistance, then there is non-zero electric field inside, because without it current wouldn't flow constantly. This electric field can only come from electric charge on the conductor surface (or other bodies like the battery).
If the conductor is superconducting, zero electric field is needed inside the conductor to maintain constant current, thus the charge distribution on the surface need not be present. If it isn't present, then electric field of the system vanishes everywhere.

The electric field in a CC circuit is the derivative of the potential with respect to the distance. In a copper conductor the resistance is very low, and a voltmeter will show zero volts between any of its  points. So, the electric field is negligible.
